# Shiny error after deploying to generate a website

Tags: r, shiny

I would like help with the following question: my app is running normally in Rstudio, however, when I deploy, and the site is generated, an error occurs. I inserted the image for you to see.
Could you help me solve it?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: try rm(DadosCompleto) in RStudio, and run the App. Is it still working?

Comment: It didn't work in Rstudio, after I used rm. It looks like this::                                                > rm(DadosCompleto)
> runApp('C:/Users/Jose Souza/Downloads/APPFINAL.R')
Error in dropNulls(list(value, min, max)) : 
 objeto 'DadosCompleto' not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run Shiny app in RStudio, the app uses the global environment.
You have in this environment an object (`DadosCompleto`) necessary for the app to run : this is what the error message is telling you.

When you deploy the app on a Shiny server, the object `DadosCompleto` doesn't exist anymore, and you have to make sure to provide it to the app.

One possibility, if creation of `DadosCompleto` takes too much time and would delay the app, is:

1. to create the object `DadosCompleto` with an R script beforehand
2. to save it at the end of this data creation script using `saveRDS`:

```
saveRDS(object = DadosCompleto,file = "data/DadosCompleto.RDS")
```

You should then load the object in the `server` code of the app :

```
DadosCompleto <- readRDS('data/DadosCompleto.RDS')
```

For this to work, you have **to make sure to copy the `DadosCompleto.RDS` file on `data/` directory of your app on the server.**

Comment: Hello Waldi, any idea for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092033/issue-involving-map-generation-in-shiny

Comment: @Jose, I won't be able to help you on this one : I don't know sfnetworks well